# How can I see ink level Printer Epson Stylus C79 in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: printing

Yesterday I was printing a document. Suddenly it stopped at the middle of the page. I got the paper out. Now when I turn on the printer it has a green light and a red one. I've changed the 4 cartidges a couple of month, more or less. I can't know if is there any of them empty or in which state is it. Which app can I use to see the status? I tried several programms which appears on Google but no way. I need urgently the printer to do some work I have.
Thank you in advance if you can help me.

Comment: If your printer actually reports ink-level, you could use `man notifier mail.to`. Check through the logs in `/var/log/cups/` to see if it does, something like `zgrep ink /var/log/cups/*`